# Movement lag in TileMap during swipe

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-x

I am developing a game with an isometric tilemap (44x44 size). I have trouble with moving the map during a swipe on the iPad-1, but it runs fine on an iPad-2. Moving the map is not smooth even if there is only the map without sprites.

I use easeout action to give retarded motion:

```
_tileMap->runAction(CCEaseOut::create(CCMoveTo::create(time, bottomLeft),2))
```

or

```
[tileMap runAction:([CCEaseOut actionWithAction:([CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:time position:postion]) rate:2 ])]
```

I tried 2d projection and turned off subpixel rendering (in ccConfig.h). But still this problem exists.

My swipe handler function is like this..

```
void GameController::SwipeHander(CCPoint vector,float speed)
{  
 CCPoint change=ccpMult(vector, speed/(1000));  //it is a wh
 CCPoint bottomLeft =ccpSub(_tileMap->getPosition(), change); //point where map gonna move  

// just to check bottomleft comes in bounding box
if (bottomLeft.x >0) {
    bottomLeft.x = 0;
}
if (bottomLeft.y>0) {
    bottomLeft.y = 0;
}
if (bottomLeft.x < -(mapWidth*_tileMap->getScale() - _screenSize.width)) {
    bottomLeft.x = -(mapWidth*_tileMap->getScale()- _screenSize.width);
}
if (bottomLeft.y <-(mapHieght*_tileMap->getScale() - _screenSize.height)) {
    bottomLeft.y = - (mapHieght*_tileMap->getScale() - _screenSize.height);
}

float dis=_tileMap->getPosition().getDistance(bottomLeft);
float time=(dis/speed);

 _tileMap->stopAllActions();
 _tileMap->runAction(CCEaseOut::create(CCMoveTo::create(time, bottomLeft),1.5));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only difference between the two implementations is the hardware you are running on, it sounds like you have it a processing bottleneck.  That is to say, you are asking the iPad-1 to meet a processing timeline that it cannot meet given the hardware it has inside it.

It doesn't seem unlikely you could rework the framework to improve its performance significantly...unless you wrote your own custom implementation.  This is possible, but how much time do you have?  Besides, this is the reason you use a framework instead of writing one.

Barring some knowledge that improves the performance on the iPad-1 vs. the iPad-2 (i.e. something in the framework that is actually different but fixable), it seems the best option would be to take some kind of performance degradation when operating on the iPad-1.

Options:

1. By default, the frame rate is set to 60 fps.  You should be able to get away with 30 fps.  Turn down the frame rate if the device is an iPad-1. You can also reduce it only at key times (e.g. The action reduces the frame rate, performs the effect, then increases the frame rate when done).
2. Different interfaces.  Use lower resolution graphics on the iPad-1 vs. the iPad-2 (or other) systems.
3. Use a "jump" instead of a smooth move on the iPad-1.
4. Profile your game and find out where the bottleneck for time is.  If you have a massive AI infrastructure (running lots of searches?), figure out a way to shut these off when the action is going on.
5. Something else...do you have to make it work **exactly** the same on the oldest platform or do you **just have to make it work**?

Comment: I am testing swipe with only tileMap on a Layer nothing else(no other processing) with low resolution image, still it lags.I know iPad can handle this. In future i going to add hundreds of sprite to it and i don't know what i am gonna do then.

Comment: Did you check the frame rate set for Cocos2d-x?

Comment: I can't speak to the hardware differences, but if that is causing it, your best bet, at that much of a drop, is to do something like option 3:  Don't do the movement if you can get the effect some other way (i.e. just jump the screen instead instead of using animation).

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem for ipad 1 and my boss too did not agree with the "jump". So instead of using the easeout you could just make the swipe work without the retarded motion.
But if perfection is the oxygen you breathe i'd suggest using a call back function and decreasing the velocity vector by some factor in each iteration. That should work